# Spark 2.0 Cassandra Scala Shell Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce$class

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have configured spark 2.0 shell to run with datastax cassandra connector.

```
spark-shell --packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:2.0.0-M1-35-s_2.11
```

When running this snippet in the shell

```
sc.stop
import org.apache.spark
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._
import com.datastax.spark
import com.datastax.spark._
import com.datastax.spark.connector
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql._
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector._

val conf = new SparkConf(true).set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "dbserver")
conf.set("spark.cores.max", "1")

val sc = new SparkContext("spark://localhost:7077", "test", conf)
val table = sc.cassandraTable("blackwell", "users")
println(table.count)
```

On this line

```
println(table.count)
```

Getting this error
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce$class

```
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 2) / 6]
16/08/25 11:59:38 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, 0.0.0.0): 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce$class
at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.CountingIterator.<init>(CountingIterator.scala:4)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.compute(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:336)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce$class
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Has anyone seen this issue?

Comment: Do you run Spark with Scala 2.10 or 2.11?

Comment: I've installed Scala 2.10.4 on the server however here is what I see in the shell.
Using Scala version 2.11.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_91). How can I change the version being used by spark?

Comment: 1.5.1 isn't compatible with spark 2.0 even if you get past this scala mismatch error.

Comment: I tried with 2.0.0-M1-35, same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got this working. 
I've added a gist for reference.

https://gist.github.com/ghafran/19d0067d88dc074413422d4cae4cc344

Here is the entire script:

```
# install java
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common -y
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
sudo apt-get install wget -y
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk -y
sudo apt-get update -y

# make serve directory
sudo mkdir -p /srv
cd /srv

# install scala 2.11
sudo wget http://downloads.lightbend.com/scala/2.11.7/scala-2.11.7.deb
sudo dpkg -i scala-2.11.7.deb

# get spark 2.0
sudo wget http://d3kbcqa49mib13.cloudfront.net/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
sudo tar -zxf spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
sudo mv spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7 spark

# build spark cassandra connector
echo "deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 642AC823
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https -y
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install sbt -y
git clone https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector.git
cd spark-cassandra-connector
git checkout v2.0.0-M2
sudo sbt assembly -Dscala-2.11=true

# move spark cassandra connector to spark jar directory
find . -iname "*.jar" -type f -exec /bin/cp {} /srv/spark/jars/ \;

# start master
/srv/spark/sbin/start-master.sh --host 0.0.0.0

# start slave
/srv/spark/sbin/start-slave.sh --host 0.0.0.0 spark://localhost:7077

# start shell
/srv/spark/sbin/spark-shell --driver-class-path $(echo /srv/spark/jars/*.jar |sed 's/ /:/g')

# test
sc.stop
import org.apache.spark
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._
import com.datastax.spark
import com.datastax.spark._
import com.datastax.spark.connector
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql._
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector._

val conf = new SparkConf(true).set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "cassandraserver")
val sc = new SparkContext("spark://localhost:7077", "test", conf)
val table = sc.cassandraTable("keyspace", "users")
println(table.count)
```

Comment: Thanks @user896993 for giving such a detailed solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Spark 2.0 uses Scala 2.11.

I cannot put a comment, so this answer will be edited after answering additional question :)

I assume that you're running spark-shell located in your computer. Can you please run in shell (system shell, not Spark) command:

```
scala -version
```

Additionally, "spark://localhost:7077" in URL looks like you have Spark Standalone launched. Can you please check if that Spark distribution is build with Scala 2.11?

In my opinion, it would be also better to use --master parameter of spark-shell.

Comment: Scala code runner version 2.10.4 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL

Comment: That's it! So you have Scala 2.10. Please check if in the Path system variable you have added path to Scala 2.11, because it seems that you have there path to older version